# HTML div excess whitespace

Tags: html, css

I have a div with an image of the world map in it, and it has map icons with text overlays placed on it. However, the border of the div is way bigger than the image, and there is no margin or padding setting that makes it like that. There is also nothing that I can see that is stretching the div border, but it still stays big. Any ideas as to why this might happen?

Any help would be appreciated

Here is the code snippet that is responsible for the Continents image:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.centered {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -3;
  background: rgb(201, 67, 67);
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva,                  Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.iconImage {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Continents Picture -->
<div class="container" style="align-content: center; border: 3px solid black; padding: 0px; margin: 0%;">
    <div class="centered; padding: 0%;  margin: 0%;" style="border: 3px solid rgb(17, 0, 255)">
        <img src="continents.png" style="width: 70%;  border: 3px solid rgb(255, 0, 0)">
        <!-- North America marker -->
        <div class="iconContainer " style="border: 3px solid rgb(17, 0, 255); bottom: 30em; left: 28em; width: 3%;">
            <img src="mapMarker.png" alt="map " class="iconImage" style="position: relative;">
            <span class="overlay" style="position: relative;">North America</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Africa marker -->
        <div class="iconContainer " style="border: 3px solid rgb(17, 0, 255); bottom: 22em; left: 58em; width: 3%;">
            <img src="mapMarker.png" alt="map " class="iconImage" style="position: relative;">
            <span class="overlay" style="position: relative;">Africa</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Europe marker -->
        <div class="iconContainer " style="border: 3px solid rgb(17, 0, 255); bottom: 43em; left: 57em; width: 3%;">
            <img src="mapMarker.png" alt="map " class="iconImage" style="position: relative;;">
            <span class="overlay" style="position: relative;">Europe</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Asia marker -->
        <div class="iconContainer " style="border: 3px solid rgb(17, 0, 255); bottom: 47em; left: 75em; width: 3%;">
            <img src="mapMarker.png" alt="map " class="iconImage" style="position: relative;">
            <span class="overlay" style="position: relative;">Asia</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Australia marker -->
        <div class="iconContainer " style="border: 3px solid rgb(17, 0, 255); bottom: 33em; left: 85em; width: 3%;">
            <img src="mapMarker.png" alt="map " class="iconImage" style="position: relative;">
            <span class="overlay" style="position: relative;">Australia</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is: `<div class="centered; padding: 0%;  margin: 0%;"` ? I think you should start by removing all the CSS from the HTML and putting it in the stylesheet instead. Then you will have a clearer overview of what you're looking at.

Comment: A style tip: when you use `0` as a value, you don't need to worry about whether to write `0%` or `0px` etc. because `0` anything is just `0`.

Comment: My mistake sorry, I meant to put that in style, as a check to make sure it wasn't margins or padding causing the extra space

Answer (score 0):

add `width: min-content;` and (for firefox) `width: -moz-min-content;` to your `.container` Element.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't have any effect on the large whitespace underneath the image.

Comment: there are elements underneath the image.

Comment: I added borders to all my divs in order to see if there were any elemnts underneath, but i didnt see any. If you can point me to what i must remove i would appreciate it

Comment: remove .iconContainer and all its attributes from your css, then you will see them.